# Changing Activity content while starting via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've a listView with 10 items on it and an activity which contains a textView. I want to start the activity on listView ItemClick but with different textView in it. I am able to start the activity via intent but stuck how to change the value in textView . Is there any way to do this?

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                    switch (position){
                        case 0:
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Districts.class);
                            ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
//I want textView to display 'abc'

                        case 1:
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Districts.class);
                            ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
//I want textView to display 'xyz'

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: you mean you want to show the clicked listView item in your next activity textView ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 2):

Pass data to intent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Districts.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key","value");
ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and get it in next activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    textView.setText(value);
}
```